# Maven -DskipTests ignored

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm building a Maven project with following [SureFire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.maven-surefire-plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Problem is, that when I build it with `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`, the tests are still being executed. What could be the problem?

I tried both `-DskipTests`(which is from the [Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html)) and `-DskipTests=true`, which is added by IntelliJ Idea when I check "skip tests" checkbox.

I don't use any Maven `settings.xml`.

- Maven version: 2.2.1
- Surefire plugin: 2.3

**EDIT**
If I comment out the SureFire plugin configuration, the parameter behaves as I expect to. What could be the problem with the configuration above?

Comment: have your try -Dmaven.test.skip

Comment: farmer: EDIT: This works, but it does something different. The tests are not only disabled, but also not compiled

Reimus: Same result

Comment: could you paste the full pom.xml and i will see if i can test it

Comment: That surefire configuration is redundant. Surefire is always run even without explicitly configuring the plugin because it's a standard plugin. Get rid of the whole section and see what happens.

Comment: artbristol: It's a multimodule project with thousands of lines of poms. Is there something I could check?

Comment: Could you post your entire pom.xml?

Comment: en. i think you can check if `pom.xml` has a parent `pom.xml`

Comment: Please see my edit. I think the problematic part of the pom is what I've already posted.

Comment: Are your tests in the standard `src/test/java` directory for each of your modules or in different locations? What is the purpose of having the section you posted in your POM?

Comment: yes, they are in the correct place. The reason for the configuration is, that I have a class TestSettings which I use for static configuration and I don't want it to be executed as a JUnit test. I only want files like ```xxxTest.java``` tested.

Comment: Don't you use decorations to mark which classes/methods are part of your actual test suite?

Comment: artbistol: It helped, but I don't see why. I need the configuration, because I don't like the default pattern for what is and isn't a JUnit test.
Nicola Musatti: I don't know what that is so I think no.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj What version of surefire are you using?

Comment: @JamesB. I was using 2.3. When I upgraded to newer version it is fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just rename `TestSettings` to something without Test in the name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you did should work. How to debug this further:

1. Run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see the whole POM that Maven will execute. Search it for `test` (case insensitive) to see if there is something odd.
2. Run `mvn test -X` to get debug output. This will print the options used to configure the `maven-surefire-plugin`. Make sure you redirect the output to a file!

   In the log, you will see

   ```
   [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test' with basic configurator -->
   ```

   and then, some lines below that:

   ```
   [DEBUG]   (s) runOrder = filesystem
   [DEBUG]   (s) skip = false
   [DEBUG]   (s) skipTests = false
   ```

   These values mean that tests aren't skipped.
3. Are you using a recent version of the plugin? [Check here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). Maybe this option wasn't supported for your version.

Comment: In step 1 I don't see anything odd, but I don't know exactly what to look for either. 
I see none of these parameters in step 2. these are the parameters I have(which I think could mean something in this problem): forkMode=once; childDelegation=false; parallel=false;useFile=true

Comment: Which version of the plugin?

Comment: Update to version 2.15. 2.3 is pretty old. Maybe it doesn't support the compact syntax.

Comment: ahh... now I understand it. It works when I remove the surefire configuration exactly because it uses newer version otherwise.

Comment: @AaronDigulla you seem to have been the first to suggest updating surefire. Why don't you post your comment as an answer so that NeplatnyUdaj can accept it? This would give you a little reputation increase and make the solution much more visible.

Comment: Nicola: I was about to suggest that too :)

Answer (score 67):

Maven knows two types of parameters for skipping tests:

```
-Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

or

```
-DskipTests=true
```

The [surefire-plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html) only mentions the first one, which you have not tried yet.

Comment: But maven.test.skip also skips compiling the tests. This is not necessarily what the OP wants.

Comment: Is it possible to compile tests and just not run them?

Comment: The flag you are using should do that @NeplatnyUdaj

Comment: Yes. It should. Apparently my surefire plugin configuration breaks it. Please see the edit of the original post.

Answer (score 12):

it is not `-DskipTests=true` it is just `-DskipTests` considering you are using surfire version 2.3

so you run it as

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

Comment: I do this all the time. But my surefire version is 2.5.. I just tried it with 2.3 surefire version and it is ignoring the skipTests. Can you tried it with 2.5?

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. It perfectly explains the behavior I observed

Comment: both can be used -DskipTests being just more convenient

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the correct answer hasn't been posted yet. In older versions of SureFire the flag to compile tests but not run them is `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec`.

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's old question, but maybe my case help for someone.

So, -DskipTests/-DskipTests=true/-DskipITs/etc didn't work, and I didn't know why. 
I had `<profiles>` in my parent `pom.xml` and problem was in configuration of surefire/failsafe.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>unit-test</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <properties>
                <skip.unit-tests>true</skip.unit-tests>
                <skip.integration-tests>false</skip.integration-tests>
                <skip.end-to-end-tests>true</skip.end-to-end-tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
...
</profiles>
```

In plugins configuration I used like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skip.unit-tests}</skipTests>
    </configuration>
...
</plugin>
```

This command didn't work:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs
```

This works:

```
mvn clean install -Dskip.unit-tests=true -Dskip.integration-tests=true -Dskip.end-to-end-tests=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following configuration for your surefire plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.surefire.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Exactly. I want them to be executed on the build server and when someone checkout the code. I just need to disable them in my project configuration

Comment: You can create distinct Maven build profiles for distinct scenarios in which you'd need either to skip or execute the tests

Comment: This seems like an overkill for such simple thing.